# Why can't I Put using API to S3 cors error

Tags: amazon-s3

I want to upload a file (PDF) form to my site S3 using API. I have configured everything IAM role and policy.

When I try to upload the file from POSTMAN - everything works fine, file was uploaded:

[image]

But when I try do this from my index.html I get this error:

[image]

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong, or any other method to do this?

This is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Przesyłanie pliku</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="file" id="fileInput">
  <button onclick="uploadFile()">Wyślij plik</button>

  <script>
    function uploadFile() {
      var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
      var file = fileInput.files[0];
      var myHeaders = new Headers();
      myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/pdf");

      var requestOptions = {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: myHeaders,
      body: file,
      redirect: 'follow'
      };

    fetch("https://v9j07k5dj0.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/dev/umarzamy-chf-upload/file.pdf", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to upload file from my site to s3

Answer (score 0):

You are blocked by CORS of API Gateway but not AWS S3. You may enable CORS for you API gateway.

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors-console.html